# Universal rendering react components using serverless, react-router, lambda, api gateway and cloudflare

Tags: react-router, cloudflare, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I'd like to do Universal rendering of react components using serverless, react-router, lambda, API gateway and Cloudflare. How would you map the API gateway endpoint URLs to a server-side instance of react-router running inside an AWS lambda function in a way that was compatible with Cloudflare?

I found an interesting hack/approach to doing it with CloudFront ( http://highscalability.com/blog/2015/12/7/the-serverless-start-up-down-with-servers.html ), but I'd prefer using Cloudflare for cost and DDoS attack prevention reasons.

Thanks!

Comment: OK, so go for it and report back with specific issues you encounter.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz, I'm just wondering if anyone has already done this.

Comment: For downvoters, which stackexchange site would be more relevant?  The serverless framework docs specifically recommend stackoverflow.  Thanks.

Comment: To my knowledge this'd fall under "too broad" on all of the Stack Exchange sites. That a site unaffiliated with the network links here doesn't mean all questions you have are thus automatically on-topic.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz.  I felt it was incredibly specific.  What would make it more specific?

Comment: Specific? There's no question in your post, and "has anyone done this?" is probably answered as "yes". Try setting up a serverless infrastructure with CloudFlare and come back with actual issues encountered.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz, asked a more specific question.